# Create a portion of a Vector in Java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I have a `Vector< MyClass > myvector`;  with size 0 - 400 and I'd like my method to return a new Vector with the positions 0-100 if exists. But my code:

```
return (Vector< MyClass >) myvector.sublist( 0, Math.min(myvector.size,100) );
```

crashes with at the return line.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2053): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList
```

What am I doing wrong? how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well... first, `myvector.sublist` should be `myvector.subList`, so that code shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 4):

`Vector<MyClass>.subList()` returns a `List<MyClass>`.  `List<MyClass>` cannot be converted to a `Vector<MyClass>`.

It's often suggested that, in general, you should work with references-to-interface-types, not references-to-concrete-types wherever possible.  Following this advice avoids this sort of conundrum.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of [Vector.subList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) is not necessarily of class Vector, but rather an implementation of a List. You can solve this problem by:

```
return new Vector<MyClass>(myvector.subList(0, Math.min(myvector.size(), 100)));
```

Edit: Thanks Stjepan and Steve for noting the unnecessary conditional.

Comment: why the if/else and not just return new Vector<MyClass>(myvector.subList(0, Math.min(myvector.size(), 100))); ?

Comment: @Stjepan Rajko Originally when I wrote it, I thought the `myvector.size() == 0` case would create an error -- but looking closer, it turns out that really isn't the case. I suppose I could make the excuse of readability, but that would be a little thin ;-)

Comment: Size will never be less than 0, so the `return new Vector<MyClass>(myvector.subList(0, Math.min(myvector.size(), 100)));` will never be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Sublist is returning a List if you want to do this you will have to do this:

```
new Vector(myList);
```

Answer (score 1):

because sublist returns a list not a vector